# Is there a way to install apps by copying it to /data/app

Tags: android, installation

To install app with adb I use

```
adb push app.apk /data/app
```

And then app installs.

But when I just copy file with RootExplorer to /data/app, it copies, but don't install. It just lies there.

Is there a way to install apps with Terminal Emulator for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the way to install apps is:

```
adb install app.apk
```

If you want to do it programmatically, you will have to use an `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/app.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

In the case above, the apk is in the SDCard directory.